# How to enable SSL self signed certificate in AFNetworking 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlerrordomain

I've to add SSL to an old project done with `AFNetworking 1.X`. I've set filling mode to `AFSSLPinningModeCertificate` however it still gives me bellow error.[image]

Answer (score 0):

its just a simple thing. only put this.

```
AFSSLPinningModeNone
```